# Does accessing information returned from an action creator in a component break Flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

When performing an action in a component does it break the Flux pattern to access the promise returned from the action creator within the component?

**Action Creators**

```
class MyActionCreators extends Marty.ActionCreators {
  create() {
    this.dispatch(MyActionConstants.CREATE_ACTION);

    return MyActionAPI.create()
      .then(res) {
        this.dispatch(MyActionConstants.CREATE_ACTION_DONE);
        return res;
      };
  }
}
```

**Compoment**

```
class MyCompoment extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onChange={ this._clickAction }>Create Me!<button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // private
  _clickAction() {
    MyActionCreators.create()
      // Does this break Flux?
      .then((res) => {
        this.context.router.transitionTo('some_path', { id: res.id });
      });
  }
}
```

Are stores the only appropriate place to access this information required in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

This does break Flux because it moves state away from a store and has the action directly communicating with the view.

---

### A possible solution

Making some assumptions on your system, I am going to assume you have a single router that you are trying to update.

**Note: Examples are not complete, they just give the basic idea. They are also not based on any implementation of the Flux architecture.**

#### The Store

Create a store that will contain the id. The store must emit some sort of change event.

**Example**

```
var Store = function() {
    this._id;
    Dispatcher.on(MyActionConstants.CREATE_ACTION_DONE, function(payload) {
        this._id = payload.id;
        this.emit("change");
    }.bind(this));
}

Store.prototype.getId = function() {
   return this._id;
}
```

#### The Controller-View

Create a controller-view (similar to your react component) that will update the router based on a change in the store.

**Example**

```
var store = new Store();
store.on('change', function() {
   router.transitionTo('some_path', { id: store.getId() })
});
```